# WebClient Download file got error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

```
WebClient ws = new WebClient();
ws.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
 ws.DownloadFile("https://xxxx.xxxx.com/xxxx.xml", @"C:\Windows\TEMP\Downloaded.xml");
```

I got error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.
Anyone know why?

If I copy the "https://xxxx.xxxx.com/xxxx.xml" to browser, it can download and save to "C:\Windows\TEMP\Downloaded.xml", but my program can not, only throw the error.

Previously I use the same code successfully download the file, but that was another site with 'http'. Not sure whether it's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure about the httpS ?

Comment: Also did you set correctly the domain ?

Comment: If this is the literal code then only username, password or domain could be null.

Comment: Thank you @HenkHolterman username, password and domain are not null, I can see from tracing.

Comment: Hi @Emged I'm not sure whether is https cause the problem, the domain is correct.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace from the exception.

Comment: Hi @HenkHolterman I got more detail error: The application terminated with an error.The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same issue when using the WebClient class. What I did was build an URI instead of the string path like this (I've not done it here, but you can also add username and password to the UriBuilder):

```
var uriBuild = new UriBuilder { Host host, Path = downloadPath };
client.DownloadFileAsync(uriBuild.Uri, localPath);
```

The host and download path is seperated, for example:

```
string host = "ftp.sunet.se"
string downloadPath = "/pub/unix/databases/relational/mysql/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.22-win32.msi"
```

Let me know if this also works for you!
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

use uri instead of using original url

```
Uri URL = urlAddress.StartsWith("https://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? new Uri(urlAddress) : new Uri("https://" + urlAddress);
await myWebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(URL, location);
```